# SMTP server not allowing attachment size with 2 mb compressed file while server max attachment size is 3 mb?

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm writing a scheduler to send e-mail to certain ids with compressed text report as zip attachment. Report i'm generating contains tons of data. So i'm splitting it into equal parts and compressing them. But server is refusing to send the mail. Following is the stack trace.

> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "TURN", arg "" DEBUG SMTP: Found extension
>   "SIZE", arg "2097152" 52 4.3.1 Message size exceeds fixed maximum
>   message size DEBUG SMTP: got response code 552, with response: 552
>   4.3.1 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size RSET 250 2.0.0 Resetting com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552 4.3.1 Message
>   size exceeds fixed maximum message size   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1634)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:889)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:338)
>     at com.bi.spring.SpringMailer.sendMail(SpringMailer.java:57)    at
>   com.bi.core.InitiateMail.main(InitiateMail.java:40)

I have checked with infra team. They said max attachment limit is 3MB. Question here is even if i reduce the attachment size to 1.2,1.5 mb which is compressed text file of 12,15 mb respectively.

Following debug message remains same for any attachment size

> DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "2097152"

My code to send mail is:

```
public void sendMail(String dear, String content ,List<String> fileList) {
   try
   {

       Calendar             calendar     =   Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
          SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat ("MMMM yyyy");
          Date date = calendar.getTime();
            String dateString=format.format(date);



        for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
        {
             MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

            helper.setFrom(simpleMailMessage.getFrom());
            helper.setTo(simpleMailMessage.getTo());

            helper.setText(String.format(simpleMailMessage.getText(), dear, content+dateString));
            helper.setSubject(simpleMailMessage.getSubject()+dateString+" | Part-"+(i+1));
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(fileList.get(i));
            helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
            try{
            mailSender.send(message);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Logger.log("Exception while sending the message|"+e.toString(),5);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            file=null;
            helper=null;
            message=null;
        }

     }
     catch (MessagingException e) 
     {
     Logger.log("MessagingException in SpringMailer|sendMail() "+e.toString(), 5);
     }
    catch (MailParseException e) 
     {
     Logger.log("MailParseException in SpringMailer|sendMail() "+e.toString(), 5);
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
        Logger.log("Exception in SpringMailer|sendMail() "+e.toString(), 5);
     }

}
```

Above is the main code for sending email. Please tell me what i'm missing here?

Edit1: I have edited the code as suggested. Now exception is gone. But only first mail got delivered. Remaining are not delivered. I observer the following debug message from logs. But remaining mails have not delivered.

**Queued mail for delivery
QUIT**

Edit2: I have checked with our infra team. Apparently there was some issue with SMTP server. After switching to other server, it started to work as expected.

Comment: The message-size != file size... Files when sending with email are base64 encoded, increasing the size considerably...

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any way i can change the encoding? I even tried with compressed 1 mb file. It supposed to send 5 mails in the loop. But it sends only one mail successfully with same exception and no trace of remaining mails? Am i missing anything here?

Comment: To understand the actual size of the message you're sending, you can write it out to a file using the Message.writeTo method.  That will help you understand whether the compressed and encoded content is larger than the limit in the server.  The SIZE message above is just the server telling you the maximum size it allows.

Comment: Your loop is flawed also as it will stop as soon as an exception occurs. Put a try/catch around the `mailSender.send` to have it continue regardless of an exception. It is even flawed more as you are sending the same message over and over and keep adding files to it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for highlighting it. Noted. Will correct it. newbie's mistakes. Everything in the message will be same. Only thing changes is subject line specifying sequence of report chunk and the attachment chunk.